# How do you solve the equation $6g + 8 = 9g - 25$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

$6g+8=9g-25$

Can you simply solve for $g$? I'm having trouble with the steps.

Comment: show some efforts from your side. it is not that much tough as you think it is.

Comment: 1) solve, not slove 2) this is not geometry 3) show your attempts and the place where you get stuck 4) in fact, the question is so basic that the question will probably get deleted

Comment: Hint: Add 25 on both sides of the equation and substract 6g on both sides of the equation.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include any work you have done on the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: Hint: you have 10 fingers and one talia. ;-)

Comment: Just an observation; replace the math in this question with an integral and for some reason it'll end up with 2-5 up votes. Same lack of Op effort, yet for some reason people think the question is fundamentally better...

Comment: @Zach466920 I have made similar observations.

Comment: @calculus well it's good not to be alone on this :)

Comment: @Zach466920 I think we are both not alone. I often make an upvote, if the downvotes are getting excessive-especially, if it is the first question. Your comment to the answer is nice, too.

Comment: I love how I am a 15 year old having trouble with a math question, and all you people are doing is giving smart remarks  expect for the ones that are actually being nice enough to give me hints  I'm on my summer vacation, away from school and I forgot a few things but nice going . I will not be using this site anymore for my future math questions and for @lisyarus , I do know how to spell "solve" but it's called typing fast and accidentally misspelling a word ✌

Comment: @Talia there's a button for editing the post, you should have used it.

Comment: I'm new to the webiste. Haven't even been here for an hour. And you was one of the first people to comment ✌✌✌✌✌

Comment: @Talia I'm 16, so I can say that you shouldn't pout when your questions aren't well received, just find out what went wrong, and try to improve your future questions. This site is a learning experience not a calculator. For instance you could use Wolfram Alpha to solve problems like these. Best of luck! :)

Comment: This situation is almost unique. A question, which has been downvoted several times at the beginning has turned into a question with net positive votings.

Answer (score 7):

we have to solve $$6g+8=9g-25$$ adding $25$ on both sides we get
$$6g+33=9g$$ substracting $6g$ this gives
$$33=3g$$ and dividing by $3$ and you have the answer.

Comment: +1 Thanks for leaving some of the work to be done by Op :)

Comment: Aside from a few very minor stylistic quibbles, this is exactly the answer I would have given.

Answer (score -1):

This is one of the toughest questions I have seen on this site, but here are some steps that might lead to the solution.

We start with the original equation $$6g + 8 = 9g - 25$$ We take the square on both sides to get $${(6g + 8)}^2 = {(9g - 25)}^2$$ Expanding both sides, we get $$36g^2 + 96g + 64 = 81g^2 - 450g + 625$$Subtracting $81g^2 - 450g + 625$ from both sides leaves $$-45g^2 + 546g - 561 = 0$$

This is a quadratic equation, so we can use the famous [Quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) to get the solutions: $$ g = \frac{-546 \pm \sqrt{{546}^2 - 4 \cdot -45 \cdot -561} }{2 \cdot -45} $$ which simplifies to $$ g = \frac{546 \mp \sqrt{197136} }{90} $$

Now, the square root of 197136 is 444, so this leaves us with $$ g = \frac{546 \mp 444 }{90} $$ so $g$ is either $\frac{102}{90}$ or $\frac{990}{90}$. When you plug both values into the original equation, you will see which one is the real solution.

Comment: The answer is 11 .

Comment: Why do you made such a unconvenient transformation by taking the square on both sides ?

Comment: Because this is (a bad attempt at) a joke.

Comment: hm just for "upvoting" $990/90=11$

Comment: "jokes" should be reserved for comments.

Comment: And now consider a version with cubes, nor squares. I will upvote it, too. :-)

Comment: Horrible joke  took me straight to sleep

Comment: -1 Agreed with @Talia.